# How to get fuzzy/blurred edges on a 3D object ? Ghibli look rock

Tags: eevee-render-engine, edges, blur, npr

[image]

Hi everyone ! I've been going through a great tutorial to get this Ghibli-like rock shader (by Kristof Dedene) and to push more the exercise I'd like to get those blurry/fuzzy edges on my 3D rock.

This is made in Eevee and it's a UV Sphere with a Voronoi texture displace modifier on top (maybe that complicate the thing ? not sure).

If you need more informations, let me know. Thank you !

Comment: Maybe give a little bit of blur in the Compositor?

Comment: ... or pull focus with Depth of Field set shallow?

Comment: Mixing Depth of field and Blur in compositing does the job, few tweakings and it will be good ! thank you both !